# how to close client pop up windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I close all child popup windows which are already opened using jquery, after the user logs out?

Comment: Your question will more likely receive answers when you provide more contextual information. This question is just about as vague as "how do I build a car?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your question is quite vague but maybe you should try to store the references to the popup windows e.g. in an array and close all those windows when logging out. The exact code depends on how you open the popups.

```
var openedPopups = new Array();
openedPopups.push($.openPopup(...));
...

(logging out)
for (var i=0, len=openedPopups.length; i<len; i++) {
  openedPopups[i].close();
}
```